# Syntax error when attempting to change row values with Pandas Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, syntax-error

I am running into a syntax error with the following:

```
df['storetype'] = df.apply(lambda x: "TP" if x.storetype == "MT", axis=1)
```

I am trying to check if the value in the storetype column is "MT" and if so change it to "TP".
Not well versed with lambda functions, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are missing an `else` in the `if` in the lambda... `x if condition else y`

Comment: @user14654909 what if there is no need for an else? shouldn't I be able to use only an If? I dont have any other value to return so the else is not necessarry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `else` is required in this ternary form. If you want to do nothing in the `else` case, you can give back the original value with `else x.storetype`:

```py
df['storetype'] = df.apply(lambda x: "TP" if x.storetype == "MT" else x.storetype, axis=1)
```